# Java Android Show with a recyclerview the strings of an array with an external layout

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I'm developing an activity that makes the user create a post, so when the user clicks on a button, a layout must be made visible that makes the user choose what genre the movie is:

```
 cTBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                postaCardVIew.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                cT.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            //The recyclerview should start here



            }
        });
```

I have an array that contains all genres:

```
 String genrelist[] = {"Commedia", "Animazione", "Anime", "Avventura", "Azione", "Biografico", "Documentario", "Drammatico", "Fantascienza","Fantasy",
                "Guerra", "Horror", "Musical", "Storico", "Thriller", "Western", "Giallo", "Sentimentale",
        };
```

I also created a layout with a cardview which will then be inflated which then represents all the items:

[image]

I would like to understand how to use recyclerview to output on each cardview one genre by one contained in the array. I have tried to look for the documentation online but it is still not clear to me. Could somebody help me?

Comment: Since, you have a small list of items. You should use a ListView instead of RecyclerView inside a PopupWindow.

Comment: @VikasChoudhary a grid view is also correct?